# how to detect mouseover rects inside SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have simple SVG chart like this:

```
<svg id="ss" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="chart" width="1000" height="300" >
    <g>
        <rect fill="#aaaaaa" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" height="1" width="1000" y="200" x="0" /> </g>
    <g class="bar">
        <rect height="81.858" width="30" y="118.142" x="10" />
    </g>
    <g class="bar">
        <rect height="111.6012" width="30" y="88.3988" x="55" />
    </g>
    <g class="bar">
        <rect height="66.98639999999999" width="30" y="133.0136" x="100" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

How to use pure javascript to detect mouse over the rect element? And knowing which rect element is being over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with directly assigning the event?

```
var rects = document.querySelectorAll( 'rect' );
for( var rect of rects ) {
    rect.addEventListener( 'mouseover', cb );
}

function cb(){
  // the "this" object is your reference to the rect hovered over
  console.log( this );
}
```

Comment: This should work, or maybe they could put all the rect groups in another group and put a single handler on that (and check this.target?)

Comment: I receive this error, when I attempt this solution:


ReferenceError: rect is not defined
 

rect.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);

Comment: @DougDexter Then use the "old" `for` loop style: `for( var i=0; i<rects.length; i++){ var rect = rects[i]; ...`